# Read large number with oracle odbc

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc

I've an Oracle table with a column of type `NUMBER(38,0)`

I need to fetch this column to my C# application.

I use the library `System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader` to read the data from my Oracle table.

I've tried fetching the data by using the normal functions like:

```
var data = oracleReader["COLUMN"].ToString();
```

And

```
var data = oracleReader.GetString(0);
```

And even the `oracleReader.GetBytes()` function.

But I always get `System.OverflowException`, because the `OdbcDataReader` always try to get the column as `decimal` in the last step:

```
System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetDecimal(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i, TypeMap typemap)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Odbc.DbCache.AccessIndex(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.internalGetString(Int32 i)
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
```

I'm happy if I can get this data as a `String` to my Application.

**FYI, I can not change the datatype of the column, I need to work with this.**

Answer (score 0):

This data type is an alias for the NUMBER(38) data type, and is designed so that the OracleDataReader returns a System.Decimal or OracleNumber instead of an integer value. Using the .NET Framework data type can cause an overflow.

Come to think of it you actually need [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) to be able to represent the same number of significant digits as to what NUMBER defaults to. I've never seen anyone do that and I would suppose it's a very rare need. Also BigInteger still wouldn't cut it since NUMBER can be of positive and negative infinity.

You can use [this list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk72thhd.aspx) for future research.

Comment: Is there anyway to bypass the .NET representation? I just need to data into my application in any format. My problem is not how to represent the data when I finally have it.

Comment: If you try: object data = oracleReader["COLUMN"], does it throw an exception?

Comment: It's hard to help you without seeing the code. Tell me the value you're trying to get. I guess you have to pass by .NET types. Try methods like: GetDouble() and GetDecimal().